# Weka - Measuring testing time

Tags: weka

I'm using Weka 3.6.8 to carry out some machine learning and I'm want to find the 'time taken to test model on training/testing data'. When I test a predictive model on evaluation data, this parameter seems to be missing. Has this feature been removed from Weka or is it just a setting I'm missing? All I seem to be able to find is the time taken to build the actual predictive model. (I've also checked the Weka Manual but can't find anything)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[That feature was added to 3.7.7](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/DATAMINING-400), you need to upgrade. You should be able to get this data by running the test on the command line with the -T parameter.

Comment: I just installed 3.7.9, is there a setting you need to change to get the testing time or should it come up automatically?

Comment: Well, my answer explains how to get it with the command line. But you can always try it in the GUI and see.

Comment: I believe you should see it, since the GUI is basically just showing you the command line output after formatting the command for you.

Comment: Or just modify settings to include that parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it through the Command Line and it works perfectly